# Trigger For Alter Role (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I want to create a trigger to catch ALTER ROLE/ADD MEMBER statements. Is there a way to do this, I couldn't find online.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that create trigger for alter_role does not work but add_role_member does work.

```
drop trigger if exists alter_role_trigger on all server;
go

create trigger alter_role_trigger 
on all server
for ADD_ROLE_MEMBER --ALTER_ROLE DOESN'T WORK HERE
as
begin
    declare @event_type sysname, @command nvarchar(max)
    set @event_type = eventdata().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]','nvarchar(128)')
     set   @command = eventdata().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
    select @event_type, @command

    if(@event_type='ADD_ROLE_MEMBER')
    begin
        insert into sampleDB.dbo.dropped_logins
        values(@command,getdate())
    end
end
go
```